# Complete border on ChartJS bars

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a stacked bar chart with this dataset configuration:

```
{
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#537bc4',
    borderWidth: 2,
    data: [null, null, 1.278, null],
    maxBarThickness: 100
}
```

which generates this:

[image]

The Y-axis is reversed.

As you can see, the `1.278` and `1.659` bars borders are not closing. **How to close them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `ChartDataSets.borderSkipped` to `false` or `"chartArea"` did the thing. [See](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#borderskipped).